# How to open report server manager from web browser once database is deleted?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've created a few reports in report server. Also I've added a data source to that rdl file. Now when suddenly I deleted a database of store procedures used by my rdl file, when I am trying to browse report server manger through Internet Explorer via a URL like http://pct107/ReportServer_SQL2014, this page doesn't get loaded and shows me the below error.

> The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable) Get Online Help
>   Cannot open database "Testing" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.

How to resolve this event? I'm not able to see any content except the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the location where MSReportBuilder.exe is installed there's a file called "MSReportBuilder.exe.config". You can delete this file with Report Builder closed (or save a copy to be on the safe side) then re-open Report Builder. This will stop it trying to automatically log into the server.

Comment: I can't find this file you have suggested "MSReportBuilder.exe.config". I have search for this on entire my computer but not able to find this.Can you suggest why it is not or any other approach for this?

Comment: Best place to start with is to open Report Builder and ignore the message about not being able to connect to the server. Then open Task Manager, go to Processes, right-click MSReportBuilder.exe and select "Open File Location". The file is of type "XML Configuration File".